# Can't find 'com.google.web.bindery.event.EventBinder' on classpath

Tags: maven, gwt

I want to use [`com.google.gwt.eventbinder`](https://github.com/google/gwteventbinder) which I am declaring in my `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt.eventbinder</groupId>
    <artifactId>eventbinder</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and in my `module.gwt.xml` I'm having:

```
<inherits name='com.google.web.bindery.event.EventBinder'/>
```

But for some reason I'm getting

```
[INFO] GET /recompile-requester/app
[INFO]    Loading inherited module 'com.blubb.client.web.App'
[INFO]       Loading inherited module 'com.google.web.bindery.event.EventBinder'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/web/bindery/event/EventBinder.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[INFO]    Sent error page: Failed to generate the Js recompile requester.
```

Is there anything else I have to specify in order to use the eventbinder?

---

[image]

Comment: do `mvn clean help:effective-pom' and do you still see that dependency listed in final pom ?